# What would be the proper way to write this? Need to replace a switch statement

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for some better way to write this code, since it looks very ugly. But I guess it works right, but i'm just wondering if there's some better way to write this? 
Basically, every key inside the statement needs to check for a thing just related to that key. Maybe I should just write some big if statement? Or use some JSON Object and store the key name, and the name of the name inside the check? Would appreciate some pointers on the best way to do this!

and the code isn't the real code (don't have it right now), it's just something I wrote in quickly to give an example of how the real code look.

```
switch (key) {
case 'cat':
    if (animals.check('kitty')) {
        delete animalsArray[index];
    }
    break;
case 'dog':
    if (animals.check('doggo')) {
        delete animalsArray[index];
    }
    break;
case 'hippo':
    if (animals.check('idk')) {
        delete animalsArray[index];
    }
    break;
case 'tiger':
    if (animals.check('somethingSpecificforTIGER')) {
        delete animalsArray[index];
    }
    break;
case 'toad':
    if (animals.check('idk')) {
        delete animalsArray[index];
    }
    break;
case 'horse':
case 'zebra':
    if (animals.check('ass')) {
        delete animalsArray[index];
    }
    break;

default:
    break;
}
```

Just need to improve the code :P

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Please share whatever attempts you yourself have made to improve the code, then if you get stuck we can help.

Comment: @melpomene this code would not be on-topic for CR, given "`and the code isn't the real code (don't have it right now), it's just something I wrote in quickly to give an example of how the real code look.`" Please read [the on-topic page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page for CR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an object that maps the key to the `animals.check` argument:

```
const mapping = {
    cat: "kitty",
    dog: "doggo",
    ...
};
if (mapping.hasOwnProperty(key) && animals.check(mapping[key])) {
    delete animalsArray[index];
}
```

Comment: Natural idea (+1) but given almost universal support of ES6+, wouldn't a `Map` be more natural than an object?

Comment: @JohnColeman What would a `Map` do that a simple object can't?

Comment: Somewhat opinion-based of course, but `hasOwnProperty` is kludgy boiler-plate which dates to when JavaScript didn't have good support for dictionary type data structures.

Comment: WIth a `Map` that's replaced with `if mapping.has(key)`, but the code is essentially the same. Creating the map is more verbose.

Comment: thanks that's what I meant with json object, i don't know the terms that good lol :P i'll do that, definitely makes the code looks better thanks!

Comment: @Strandza The term is just "object". JSON is the string representation used when transmitting an object over the network or storing it in a file.

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure i get what you want but can't you use something like:

```
var zoo = {
    king : 'lion',
    thief : 'snake'
}

var arr = ['lion', 'snake'];

delete arr[arr.indexOf(zoo.king)]
```

Comment: `arr[arr.indexOf(zoo.king)]` is the same as just `zoo.king`.

Comment: It is but dont you need to delete the array? Im not sure what you want to achieve

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I don't want to achieve anything, I didn't write the question.

Comment: I just don't see how this answers the question. What's the purpose of `arr`?

Comment: Is that supposed to be the same as `animalsArray` in the question?

Comment: Arr is his array, im assuming he wants to delete an array based on the object

Comment: You're also assuming that the elements of his array are the same as the values in the object. He has an `index` variable that already contains the index that he wants to delete, it doesn't seem to be related to searching the array.